# Perl - comparing downtimes

Tags: arrays, perl

Wondering if anyone has dealt iwth this kind of problem and can offer any advice:

I'm parsing a logfile to see if/when hosts are failing and what their total downtime is. My problem is I am not sure how to approach figuring out if a host falls within the time frame of another fallen host (I dont want to count them twice)

Example:

Host A falls at 14:15-14:18

Host B falls at 14:16-14:21

Host C falls at 14:17-14:20

This would result in

Host A accounting for 3 minute of downtime

Host B for 3 minutes

Host C for 0 (the other hosts were down at the time already)

Right now, I am pushing to an array upTime:downTime - I figured an array would be the easiest to walk through and compare. Not sure what the best way would be to tackle this problem though..

```
                push(@arr, "$tempdown:$upTime"); 
        }
    }
}   
}


#temp vars x and y rep downtime and uptime
#count from x..y and see if any other service has fallen within x-y
for my $index (@arr) {
my $tempx;
my $tempy;
if ($index=~/(.*):/ && /($index=~(.*:(.*)/) {
    $tempx = $1;
    $tempy = $2;
}
for ($tempx..$tempy) {
.
.
.
```

Comment: I would start with [DateTime::Set](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is tricky when only having the hours:minutes for time instead of something like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM. That could be unambiguously parsed for the time. If you could change the logger output to give a fully qualified date, it would make your job much simpler. The code below would do that. (**Disclaimer:** the start times must be in cronological order **or** it would be necessary to sort them first).

(Note: For this data, I changed the times separator from '-' to '\t')

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $re = '(\S{10}\s\S{5})\t(\S{10}\s\S{5})$';
my $max;
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%F %H:%M');

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($start, $stop) = /$re/ or die $!;

    $_ = $parser->parse_datetime($_) for $start, $stop;

    # one time initialization of $max for first record
    $max //= $start;

    # when there are breaks in the continuity
    $max = $start if $max < $start;

    my $minutes = $stop <= $max ? 0 : $max->delta_ms($stop)->in_units('minutes');

    printf "$_ %2d minutes\n", $minutes;
    $max = $stop if $max < $stop; # stop is the new max if stop > max
}

__DATA__
Host A fails at 2012-07-03 14:15    2012-07-03 14:18
Host B fails at 2012-07-03 14:16    2012-07-03 14:21
Host C fails at 2012-07-03 14:17    2012-07-03 14:20
Host D fails at 2012-07-03 23:57    2012-07-04 00:05
Host E fails at 2012-07-03 23:58    2012-07-04 00:07
Host F fails at 2012-07-04 00:00    2012-07-04 00:08
Host G fails at 2012-07-04 00:01    2012-07-04 00:09
Host H fails at 2012-07-04 00:02    2012-07-04 00:08
Host I fails at 2012-07-04 14:17    2012-07-04 14:20
Host J fails at 2012-07-04 23:57    2012-07-04 23:59
Host K fails at 2012-07-05 00:00    2012-07-05 00:10
Host L fails at 2012-07-05 00:02    2012-07-05 00:09
Host M fails at 2012-07-05 00:02    2012-07-05 00:11
Host N fails at 2012-07-05 00:02    2012-07-05 00:10
```

It produced the following output:

```
Host A fails at 2012-07-03 14:15        2012-07-03 14:18  3 minutes
Host B fails at 2012-07-03 14:16        2012-07-03 14:21  3 minutes
Host C fails at 2012-07-03 14:17        2012-07-03 14:20  0 minutes
Host D fails at 2012-07-03 23:57        2012-07-04 00:05  8 minutes
Host E fails at 2012-07-03 23:58        2012-07-04 00:07  2 minutes
Host F fails at 2012-07-04 00:00        2012-07-04 00:08  1 minutes
Host G fails at 2012-07-04 00:01        2012-07-04 00:09  1 minutes
Host H fails at 2012-07-04 00:02        2012-07-04 00:08  0 minutes
Host I fails at 2012-07-04 14:17        2012-07-04 14:20  3 minutes
Host J fails at 2012-07-04 23:57        2012-07-04 23:59  2 minutes
Host K fails at 2012-07-05 00:00        2012-07-05 00:10 10 minutes
Host L fails at 2012-07-05 00:02        2012-07-05 00:09  0 minutes
Host M fails at 2012-07-05 00:02        2012-07-05 00:11  1 minutes
Host N fails at 2012-07-05 00:02        2012-07-05 00:10  0 minutes
```

Hope this is helpful,

Chris

Comment: very much indeed. I'm going to revisit my code and I'll update this post once I've got it working. thanks a lot

Comment: Good to hear. I did a version with a sort.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you will want to have your data organized as:

- T<sub>s</sub> — the start time of a period of down time.
- T<sub>e</sub> — the end time of a period of down time.
- H<sub>t</sub> — the host 'responsible' for a period of down time.

You will be able to sort the periods of down time in order of T<sub>s</sub>.  You will need a mechanism to resolve ties where two (or more) machines start a period of down time at the same time (according to the resolution at which the times are recorded).  Further down, I suggest the secondary key is latest T<sub>e</sub>, then the tertiary key is alphabetic by host name.

You can then step through the ordered list of down time periods by T<sub>s</sub>.

For each period of down time:

- H<sub>t</sub> gets the blame for the whole of the time it is down.
- For each period of down time that starts before T<sub>e</sub>:

  - subtract the period  T<sub>s</sub> ..  T<sub>e</sub> from the down time of the other host.
- Reorder the data for the next iteration.

Given your sample data, we get:

- T<sub>s</sub> = 14:15, T<sub>e</sub> = 14:18, H<sub>t</sub> = A
- T<sub>s</sub> = 14:16, T<sub>e</sub> = 14:21, H<sub>t</sub> = B
- T<sub>s</sub> = 14:17, T<sub>e</sub> = 14:20, H<sub>t</sub> = C

This is in the correct sorted order.  We will assume that hosts with down times at the same time are sorted alphabetically.

The algorithm picks A:

- Host A gets blamed for 14:15-14:18 (3 minutes).

The periods for the other hosts are adjusted:

- T<sub>s</sub> = 14:18, T<sub>e</sub> = 14:21, H<sub>t</sub> = B
- T<sub>s</sub> = 14:18, T<sub>e</sub> = 14:20, H<sub>t</sub> = C

The algorithm now picks B

- Host B gets blamed for 14:18-14:21 (3 minutes).

The periods for the other hosts are adjusted, and the record for Host C is erased because what is left of its time is completely covered by the down time of host B.

You can see that the tie-breaker sequencing is very important; on the second iteration, both systems B and C are down, and there must be a way of deciding which is responsible for the down time once A recovers.  You might well decide that one of the criteria is 'which host originally went down first', so you keep a record of T<sub>d</sub>, the initial time a server goes down.  This does not change during the algorithm, but T<sub>s</sub> is adjusted as the algorithm progresses.  You might also decide that part of the ordering is 'latest T<sub>e</sub>' so that the machine that is down for longest at any given time gets the blame for the outage while it is down and no system that was down earlier is still down.  This means that if A also goes down from 14:19-14:30, it won't get the blame for 14:18-14:21, but it will for 14:21-14:30.